# j = *x; x = &j; (*x) = 3; why that will change the value of j in c

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote that simple code:

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int *x; // x points to an integer
    i = 1;
    x = &i;
    j = *x;
    printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j); //i = 1, j = 1
    x = &j;
    (*x) = 3;
    printf("i = %d, j = %d", i, j); // i = 1, j = 3
}
```

as we can see here that the value of j is changed after `(*x) = 3;` can someone explain what happen here.

Comment: I assume y is "j" So u have x= &j; this means that the pointer x is pointing towards the address where j is stored. by doing *x =3 is basically the same thing as doing j = 3.

Comment: And as a conseguence c = i?

Comment: I think you mean `j`, not `y`.  But why the surprise?  You set `x` to point to `j`, then you write a 3 to the target of `x`, which of course is `j`.  So `j` becomes 3.

Comment: I suggest finding a good C tutorial and reading the first few pages, at least to the point where pointers and arrays are covered.  That should help to alleviate your confusion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the question which should be answered here. We are not a teaching portal. This does not have anything common with the programmingas programming requires some level of knowledge and efffor

Comment: @PeterJ_01, I value your comment but you have to take into consideration that i'm beginner in c. I have to understand these basic things deeply, and you as expert can help me, I know that the question is low level, but that low leve things I have to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;   // declaration of i and j
    int *x;    // x points to an integer
    i = 1;     // initialization of i = 1
    x = &i;    // initialization of x = address of i
    j = *x;    // initialization of j = value of what pointed by x => j = 1

    printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j); //i = 1, j = 1

    x = &j;    // assign to x the address of j
    (*x) = 3;  // assign 3 to what pointed by x 
               // x points to j, so j = 3

    printf("i = %d, j = %d", i, j); // i = 1, j = 3
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming "y" means "j" in your case since you mention "y" changed to 3 and there is nothing else in your code that changes its value to 3:

In the line above (*x) = 3; you have x = &j; which makes x point to j. Now you are dereferencing x and change the value in whatever it points to, and that is j.